# mvc cannot call view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get started learning MVC. I built the MVC Music Store project that I found on the Microsoft site. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1.

I got it working pretty well but I ran into trouble when I tried to modified it. I want to put the data in a separate project. I used Linq to Entities for the data access.

Here is my class to access the data

```
public class clsUtilities
{
    Utilities.MVCMusicStoreEntities db = new Utilities.MVCMusicStoreEntities();

    public object GetAlbums(string GenreName)
    {
        var query = from tags in db.vieAlbumArtists
                    where tags.GenreName.Equals(GenreName)
                    select tags;

        return query;
    }
}
```

In my Controller my code is

```
public ActionResult Browse2(string genre)
{
    // retrieve Genre and its associated albums from the database

    var genreModel = mcloUtilities.GetAlbums(genre);

    return View(genreModel);
}
```

I generate a cshtml file in my view

```
@model Utilities.vieAlbumArtist

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse2";
}
```

This all compiles ok but when I run it I get:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1[Utilities.vieAlbumArtist]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `Utilities.vieAlbumArtist`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`@model Utilities.vieAlbumArtist`

to

`@model IEnumerable<Utilities.vieAlbumArtist>`

You are returning a *list* of `vieAlbumArtist`, not just a single instance.

You might also want to change

`public object GetAlbums(string GenreName)`

to

`public IEnumerable<Utilities.vieAlbumArtist> GetAlbums(string GenreName)`

Passing `objects` around is not the best idea.

Comment: You are assuming he wants a collection, when the code is not 100 percent decisive either way.

Comment: Action GetAlbums would seem to signify that they is not looking for a single item. This is the correct answer for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
public object GetAlbums(string GenreName)
```

You're returning the data as an object. But the view expects to receive an item of type `Utilities.vieAlbumArtist`.  Either change the `GetAlbums()` method to return the appropriate type, or make sure you cast it in the controller to the type the view is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the help of the hints you guys gave me.

From clsUtilies

```
  public class clsUtilities
    {
        Utilities.MVCMusicStoreEntities db = new Utilities.MVCMusicStoreEntities();

        public IEnumerable<Utilities.vieAlbumArtist> GetAlbums(string GenreName)
        {




        IEnumerable<vieAlbumArtist> query = from tags in db.vieAlbumArtists
                    where tags.GenreName.Equals(GenreName)

                    select tags;

            foreach (var n in query)
            {

            }

        return query;

        }
```

From Controller

```
 public ActionResult Browse2(string genre)
        {
            // retrieve Genre and its associated albums from the database


            var genreModel = mcloUtilities.GetAlbums(genre);


            return View(genreModel );
        }
```

From Views

```
@model IEnumerable< Utilities.vieAlbumArtist> 


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse Albums";
}





@foreach(var album in Model) 
{ 
   <ul>  
       <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id=album.AlbumId})">
       <img alt="@album.Title" src="@album.AlbumArtUrl" />
       <span>@album.Title (   @album.Name ) </span> </a>
       </ul>
} 











}
```

Answer (score -1):

To display a list of albums try this:

```
<ul>
@foreach(var item in vieAlbumArtist)
{
   <li>item.Name</li> //Not sure if you actually have a name property
}
</ul>
```

Comment: @JakubKonecki that could be possible, but his model `Utilities.vieAlbumArtist` specifics a single Artist, not a collection.

Comment: Chuck - and that's a problem. Look at the query and method names - he is retrieving a list of albums by tag.

Comment: @JakubKonecki The problem is he has not clarified whether he is showing a collection or a single item.

Comment: Chuck - I think you can infer it.

Comment: I want the collection of all albums for the genre specific. The fix from Jakub works but I need the code in the cshtml to list the albums. Cannot get it to work. What do I put after @Model or Model?

Comment: @BobAvallone Do you have anything to display the Albums?

Comment: @BobAvallone The above code should print out a list of names for your collection.

Comment: Chuck, It didn't work. It wanted me to qualify vieAlbumArtist with Utilities, but when I did i got this exception, CS0119: 'Utilities.vieAlbumArtist' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @BobAvallone Can you post your cshtml? It sounds like you have a namespace/type collision.

Comment: @model  IEnumerable< Utilities.vieAlbumArtist>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse Albums";
}


<ul> 
@foreach(var item in Utilities.vieAlbumArtist) 
{ 
   <li>item.Name</li> //Not sure if you actually have a name property 
} 
</ul>